# How to make regular expression for this in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a expression, i need to validate. I wanna do it using regular expression. Please help.

1. `AAsswwww-11233  (First 2 char are static - then any alphabets only - then hyphen - then only digits.`

Comment: Go and find out about regular expressions.

Comment: Since we're on Stack Overflow anyway, [start here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions/2759417#2759417).

Comment: At least show some evidence of having tried something first. Check out www.regular-expressions.info and see if you can work it out.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^AA[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@"^AA[A-Za-z]+[-]\d+$"
```

[Learn How to Use and Get The Most out of Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)